# Rails DB Migrations Not Running

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have multiple migrations under db/migrate:

```
# ls db/migrate
20140224203310_devise_create_users.rb   
20140224203311_add_name_to_users.rb
20170205020215_create_sites.rb      
20170703141548_add_admin_to_users.rb
```

I run db:reset and all of the migrations are listed there:

```
# rails db:reset
.......
 (25.5ms)  INSERT INTO `schema_migrations` (version) VALUES
(20140224203310),
(20140224203311),
(20170205020215),
(20170703141548);
```

but when I run db:migrate I only get the user's table:

```
# rails db:migrate
(0.4ms)  SET NAMES utf8,  @@SESSION.sql_mode = CONCAT(CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',STRICT_ALL_TABLES'), ',NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'),  @@SESSION.sql_auto_is_null = 0, @@SESSION.wait_timeout = 2147483
   (0.2ms)  SELECT DATABASE() as db
   (0.3ms)  SELECT GET_LOCK(4211445956987945865, 0)
   (0.3ms)  SELECT `schema_migrations`.`version` FROM `schema_migrations` ORDER BY `schema_migrations`.`version` ASC
  ActiveRecord::InternalMetadata Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `ar_internal_metadata`.* FROM `ar_internal_metadata` WHERE `ar_internal_metadata`.`key` = 'environment' LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
   (0.3ms)  SELECT RELEASE_LOCK(4211445956987945865)
   (0.3ms)  SELECT `schema_migrations`.`version` FROM `schema_migrations` ORDER BY `schema_migrations`.`version` ASC
   (0.3ms)  SHOW CREATE TABLE `users`
   (0.5ms)  SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'users'
```

Why is Rails not running thru all of the migrations? How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Check the output of `rake db:migrate:status`; quite likely all the migrations are run.

Comment: Migrations are temporary bits of code to get your database from A to B, the current state of things should be in `db/schema.rb` or `db/structure.sql`. So why are you expecting all your migrations to run all the time?

Comment: @muistooshort good catch. I don't typically have a db/schema.rb file (newbie) but in this case I did. I honestly did think that all migrations would run on a db:migrate. Now I know :) I reloaded the schema and now everything is there. Add your answer if you want the credit. Thanks!